# Adding Bootstrap attributes to Rails Simple Form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, slim-lang

The following form snippet is a boolean so is styled as a checkbox:

```
= form.input :recur, label: "Recurring"
```

I need two things:
1) to style it as a bootstrap button rather than a checkbox
2) add data-target and data-toggle attributes

This is the HTML code I need to add to the form for button styling and collapse functionality and I'm having a hard time figuring out the right syntax for Simple Form (I'm using SLIM):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#recurringGift" type="button">
</button>
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1) With simple form, you can pass in options to the input, label, and wrapper. I would style the label to use button classes, and set `display: none` on the input itself, since clicking the label will also select the checkbox.

eg.

```
= f.input_field :some_checkbox, input_html: { style: "display: none"}, label_html: { class: "btn btn-primary"}
```

Even better, you can put the checkbox before the label, so you can use the `:checked` pseudoclass to affect the label's style:

```
= f.input_field :some_checkbox, input_html: { style: "display: none"}
= f.label :some_checkbox, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Then in your CSS you can declare:
    input:checked + label { background-color: grey; }

eg. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doqZyp

2) You can pass data attributes with a `data: {}` hash, eg.

```
= f.input_field :some_checkbox, input_html: { style: "display: none"}, data: {target: "#recurringGift", toggle: "collapse"}
```

Be advised that you convention requires that data-attributes use hyphens to separate words (eg. `data-some-attribute=""`), but rails will want underscores (eg. `data: {some_attribute: ""}`

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The display: none is blocking the functionality, when I remove that it works fine, but the check box shows up along with the button. Any other ideas for hiding that?

Comment: You can hide it by giving it `position: absolute;` and then moving it was off-page, eg. `left: -1000em`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doqZyp

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add them as attributes by adding them to the options object:

```
= form.input :recur, label => "Recurring", 'data-toggle' => "collapse", 'data-target' => '#recurringGift'
```

Note that you must use quotes around attributes with dashes, since they aren't allowed in symbols. Also note the hash rocket notation. You can not use the colon notation when a key is a string

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's not working for me by adding them on as you wrote. Do you know if I'm able to style a boolean input as a button, not check box?